# object HTMLElement : ID and POS

Tags: javascript

In a div I have a lot of images in figure tag (i.e 10):

```
echo '<figure class="figure" id="fig'.$pos[1].'">';
echo '<img src="'.$img.'" width="auto" height="50" alt="" />';
echo '</figure>';
```

I want to add a new image in this div with a drag-drop function (pure JS, no JQ). Once the new image is dropped I get its left position.

```
console.log("OBJ "+o+" left = "+l);
-> OBJ img11.jpg left = 408
```

In the beginning of my JS I wrote an Array with offsetLeft pos of each previous image of the div :

```
console.log("FIGS posleft = "+tab_pos_l);
-> FIGS posleft = 26,125,163,262,339,377,422,485,501
```

Now I can determine which images are to move depending their left pos:

```
for (i=0; i<tab_pos_l.length; i++) {
    if ( l < tab_pos_l[i] ) { // if obj left smaller than figure left
      console.log("MOVE "+$('bloc'+i)+" ID="+$('bloc'+i).id+" LEFT="+$('bloc'+i).offsetLeft);
    }
}

// $('bloc'+i) == document.getElementById('bloc'+i);
```

and the result is:

```
  OBJECT [object HTMLElement] ID = bloc7 LEFT = 422
  OBJECT [object HTMLElement] ID = bloc8 LEFT = 485
  OBJECT [object HTMLElement] ID = bloc9 LEFT = 501
```

I can't understand why  $('bloc'+i) is undefined (but it can provide the correct offsetLeft of the image) and why $('bloc'+i).id needs an extra .id to give the real ID... And of course

```
 $('bloc'+i).style.left = ( $('bloc'+i).offsetLeft + l )+"px";
```

doesn't work.

Comment: if you're not using jQuery, what do you think `$('bloc' + i)` is supposed to return? (NB: if you _are_ using jQuery, identifier selectors have to be prefixed with a `#`)

Comment: the ID of each figure is  id="bloc'.$pos[1].'"  not   id="fig'.$pos[1].'"

Comment: if 'blick123' is your id, there is a # missing: $('#block123')

Comment: $('bloc' + i) == [object HTMLElement] :-(

Comment: leguano : no JQuery, pure JS

Comment: so is `$()` a function of your own devising?

Comment: $=function(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

Comment: OK, that makes sense (although IMHO it's not usually a good idea to write your own functions that use the same identifiers as well known APIs like jQuery).  Now the problem is that you've so much extraneous detail in your question that I can't tell what your actual question is.  Please reduce it to a _small, self contained, example_.

Comment: OK I rewrite the prob

Answer (score 0):

```
 tab_pos_l = [26,125,163,262,339,377,422,485,501];
 l = 500;

 for (i=0; i<tab_pos_l.length; i++) {
   if ( l < tab_pos_l[i] ) { 
     // document.getElementById('bloc'+i) == [object HTMLElement]
     // document.getElementById('bloc'+i).id == "bloc9"
     // document.getElementById('bloc'+i).offsetLeft == "501"
   }
 }
```

I can't understand why document.getElementById('bloc'+i).offsetLeft give the expected result but not  document.getElementById('bloc'+i). To get the real ID it requires an extra .id. So I can't modify the left pos of "bloc9" because I can't access to it in the DOM.

---

Added: I've tried another way to proceed. I put an id tag to the img with the idea to access to its parentNode (figure tag)

```
  echo '<figure id="bloc'.$dat[1].'".......>'
  echo '<img id="im'.$dat[1].'".......>'

    var b = $('im'+i).parentNode;
    console.log("B.id = "+b.id);
    console.log("B.off = "+b.offsetLeft);
    console.log("B.pos = "+b.style.left);
```

console

```
    B.id = bloc9
    B.off = 501
    B.pos =
```

---

2nd added: oh no that's incredible

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[i].getAttribute("id"); 
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[i].offsetLeft; 
document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[i].style.left = 1000+"px"; 
var z = document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[i].style.left; 
console.log(x+"="+y+"="+z);
```

console

```
bloc9=501=1000px
```

but in the div my image hasn't move. I can(t believe it